# How to get keys by initing an javascript array with "Array(arrayLength)"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an array like this:

```
let arrObj = Array(2)
arrObj.push(1)
console.log("-----init array with Array(2)-----")
console.log(arrObj)
console.log("---print index with foreach()-----")
arrObj.forEach((_, index) => console.log(index))
console.log("---print index with map()-----")
arrObj.forEach((_, index) => console.log(index))
console.log("---print index with every()-----")
arrObj.every((_, v) => console.log(v))
console.log("---print index with keys()-----")
for (const v of arrObj.keys()) {
  console.log(v)
}
console.log("---print index with findIndex()-----")
console.log(arrObj.findIndex((_, v) => v >= 0))
```

and i got the result:

```
-----init array with Array(2)-----
[ <2 empty items>, 1 ]
---print index with foreach()-----  
2
---print index with map()-----      
2
---print index with every()-----    
2
---print index with keys()-----     
0
1
2
---print index with findIndex()-----
0
```

why i got the different results with *keys()* and others?

i would appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: Because array iteration methods like `forEach` and `every` will skip missing slots in sparse arrays.

Comment: @VLAZ Thx, does it mean I can't use some methods which would skip missing slots if I want get all the indices? But how do I know which methods are for sparse arrays and which are not, only try every iteration methods ?